# How do I give style to a variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the color of button everytime it got clicked. In my code, linkNumber will get a value. and I want to give it a color. The way I did is not working. I tested with alert to make sure the values and it is working.

```
var linkNumber = $(this).text();
                $(linkNumber).css("color", "yellow");
                alert(linkNumber);
```

Comment: `$(this).text();` only gives you back whatever text is inside the tags you selected, if `$(this)` represents a button, remove the `.text()` part, remove the jQuery tags from `$(linkNumber).css` and check if it works

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are attempting to set color in the text itself. Text cannot have a color. *Containers* (tags) can have css. So just set the css color to the container.

```
$(this).css('color', 'yellow');
```

Comment: yeah it does. But it colors all the values. How do it only colors the selected one?

Comment: @ilovejava `$(this)` shouldn't return more than one element. How are you calling it? Can you put all your code into the question? Best as [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a live example of a few buttons changing color:

```js
var colors = ["yellow", "red", "blue"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var currentIndex = Number($(this).data("ci")) || 0;
    var nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.length;
    $(this).data("ci", nextIndex).css("color", colors[nextIndex]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

On the first click, the button is assumed to currently have `colors[0]`. The array index is incremented and stored in the button, then the color is assigned to it.

Comment: Okay. what if I want only one color. And the color gets changed when i clicked. For instance, if there are 3 button. If i click button 1, it gets red color and other two stays same. If I click button 2, this gets red and rest stays same.

Answer (score 0):

in this example on clicking the button the background color of the button will be changed if you want to change the color of the text inside the button you have to use **color:cyan;** insted of **background-color:cyan** property

**CSS**

```
.clickme{
background-color:cyan;
color:White;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="clickme">button1</button>
<button class="clickme">button2</button>
<button class="clickme">button3</button>
```

**jQuery function for click element**

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
$(this).css("background-color","green");
});
```

[Here is the Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/397cgxkq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can append the style directly to `this.style.color = 'yellow';`

Also I would advice against using jQuery nowadays.

```js
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'button' ) )
  .forEach( button => ( button.addEventListener( 'click', ( e ) => {
    e.target.style.color = 'red';
  } ) ) );
```

```html
<button>button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
```